# Contextual filter on a path alias

Tags: views, path-aliases

I am trying to create a page view that will display content by Content:Title which is part of the node's URL.

I have 3 content-types: *Movies*, *Books*, and *TV Shows*.

Each content type has a path alias matching the *[node:content-type:machine-name]/[node:title]/[current-date:custom:Ymd]* pattern.

I successfully created a view called movies with a filter on *Movies* that displays all the nodes with [www.example.com/movies/](http://www.example.com/movies/) in the URL. If I click on a node in the *Movies* view, it displays the content using the node.tpl.php template file.

I added a contextual filter (*Content: Title*) using Scott Edmonds suggestion.

Contextual Filter for: Content: Title ). When filter is not in URL -> Provide Default Value -> Raw Value from URL -> Path Component=2. Use Path Alias=Checked. Then, When Filter Value is In URL: Specify Validation Criteria= "PHP Code" with the following PHP code: $handler->argument = str_replace("-"," ",$argument); return true; That did the trick. the PHP code converts the dashes to spaces so it can be evaluated correctly.

The result is that when I click on the "Star Trek is Great" post link I am taken to the correct URL, [www.example.com/movies/star-trek-great/20130702](http://www.example.com/movies/star-trek-great/20130702),  but node.tpl.php is the template used instead of views-view--movies.tpl.php.

When I copy the title and paste it into the url, as "www.example.com/movies/Star Trek is Great/20130712" the views template page comes us.

Some where along the way I am missing something.  Any help out there?

FYI - I also have simply set the contextual filter on Content:Title with
Display all results for the specified field
Checked "Override title" and added %1 as the first argument
Seleced "lowercase" for the Case PATH
Selected "transform spaces to dashes in url"

But nothing worked :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the following:

When you go to `www.example.com/movies/star-trek-great/20130702` Drupal sees that this is a path alias to `node/#`, and it displays that node.  It won't use Views at all.

When you go to `www.example.com/movies/Star Trek is Great/20130712`, this does not map to any URL, but rather to the View sitting at `www.example.com/movies` with an contextual filter of `Star Trek is Great` (and `20130712` most probably).

You may have some other issues to work out as well:

Pathauto is taking out the `is` (and other small words by default) so there will be a bit of a hard time mapping `star-trek-great` to `Star Trek is Great`.

Also, what happens if you have a title of `Star Trek is Great!!!` that maps to `star-trek-great` as well?